# Additional tables in SQL Server to ensure integrity: which way?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently putting together a website which includes Entity Framework. However, I'm a bit of a database novice.

While designing the database that underpins it, I have added some extra columns that are there purely for the purpose of maintaining integrity across tables. They aren't being used by my application.

For me, it seems a bitty messy having these redundant columns in my ORM. Is it better practice to move the 'for integrity only' columns into separate tables and keep my ORM clean? I've tried removing them directly from EF, but this seems to introduce errors.

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just set them as `[EditorBrowsable(false)]`

Comment: @Charlieface And how would I apply that? I'm using EF database first.